# Game modelling how to get height details?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, unity, normal-map, height-map

I am trying to create a model for unity 3D.

To my knowledge blender - Normal map  is only going to smoothen the edges

Now how the height details are passed? What kind of texture is required?

I have a high poly model and low poly model, is there a way to do it?

[image]

Comment: are you on cycles or blender render

Comment: @Grimlock hi i am on blender cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too sure about Unity, but in blender the usual way to go from highpoly models to lowpoly models is to create a normal map from the highpoly and apply it to the lowpoly. To do this see here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOYRCI-dtjU

Hope it helps :)

Comment: the level of detail which is transferred with the normal map is less. It does not transfer height info..only details of how light should reflect is transferred. I am missing something...details marked with green arrows are not from normal map

Comment: oh I see what you mean now. One sec

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but what you're looking for is displacement maps. Here's a video on how to do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1ASzhU9O-A   however, it is specifically for sculpting, but you may be able to use the same methods in your model

Comment: Yeah, but it is the answer but is computationally more expensive. It is better to keep the normal map details height in 0.9x thickness. As far as i know

Comment: I never thought of computational performance (cause I have quite a strong GPU and CPU combination). Thanks for letting me know though, I'll keep that in mind next time :)